# Uploading PHP script by user in Joomla front-end

Tags: php, joomla

Sorry for my English and probably stupid question, but being amateur in web programming I can't find a definite, short answer for the following questions:

1. what is the danger of allowing Joomla user to upload PHP file from the front-end, and
2. is there any way to prevent the risks in (1), while allowing user to upload PHP script?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The obvious answer to 1. is that they could do _everything_ in that script that _you_ could do as well in your own. So f.e. what files they could read (got credentials for a database connection stored somewhere?) or even overwrite, is pretty much limited only by what _you_ have access to in the hosting environment. 2. gets us way out of amateur territory, and is therefor way too broad for here.

Answer (score 0):

CBroe's answer outlines the risks of letting users upload PHP script files to your web server. There are applications that allow this functionality by using automatic code generators that create the PHP script files server side, providing some kind of UI for users to do so. Some of the Content Construction Kits (CCKs) do this. Others allow authorized users (administrators) to edit PHP files directly, which mitigates the security risks by relying on trusted users to not do harm. A third approach is something like Facebook's, where they require users to host the PHP script files on the user's own server, but provide an API and SDK to integrate those apps into Facebook's system.